# MySql query successful?

Tags: mysql

I'm pretty new to MySql and needed some advice on how to write delete for this case.

```
I have two tables:TABLE_1 and a TABLE_2

TABLE_1:

       +--------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
       |ID      | NAME    | LASTNAME     |REF       |DNI          | COUNTRY   | MONTH  | LAST_DATE   | 
       +--------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
       |  1     |Juan     |Valverde      |23054     |6124123      | EEUU      |  APRIL |  2021-09-03 | 
       |  2     |Mark     |Márquez       |42451     |9751434      | MEXICO    |  MAY   |  2020-05-05 | 
       |  3     |Mary     |Jeans         |19784     |8624244      | SPAIN     |  JULY  |  2019-15-18 |
       |  4     |Phillip  |Butters       |25054     |1251244      | FRANCE    |  OCTOB |  2018-01-01 | 
       +--------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
```

TABLE_2:

```
       +--------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
       |ID      | NAME    | LASTNAME     |REF       |DNI          | COUNTRY   | MONTH  | LAST_DATE   | 
       +--------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
       |  1     |Juan     |Valverde      |23054     |6124123      | EEUU      |  APRIL |  2019-09-03 | 
       |  2     |Juan     |Valverde      |23054     |6124123      | PANAMA    |  JAN   |  2021-06-10 | 
       |  3     |Mark     |Márquez       |42451     |9751434      | MEXICO    |  MAY   |  2020-05-05 | 
       |  4     |Mark     |Márquez       |42451     |9751434      | GERMANY   |  JUN   |  2021-09-03 | 
       |  5     |Mary     |Jeans         |19784     |8624244      | SPAIN     |  JULY  |  2016-15-18 |
       |  6     |Mary     |Jeans         |19784     |8624244      | PORTUGAL  |  JULY  |  2017-10-10 | 
       |  7     |Mary     |Jeans         |19784     |8624244      | PERU      |  FEB   |  2015-05-30 |
       |  8     |Phillip  |Butters       |25054     |1251244      | FRANCE    |  OCTOB |  2018-01-01 | 
       |  9     |Phillip  |Butters       |25054     |1251244      | BRAZIL    |  DEC   |  2018-04-01 | 
       +--------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
```

The result would look something like this:

TABLE_1:

```
       +--------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
       |ID      | NAME    | LASTNAME     |REF       |DNI          | COUNTRY   | MONTH  | LAST_DATE   | 
       +--------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
       |  1     |Juan     |Valverde      |23054     |6124123      | EEUU      |  APRIL |  2021-09-03 | 
       |  3     |Mary     |Jeans         |19784     |8624244      | SPAIN     |  JULY  |  2019-15-18 |
       +--------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
```

**I want to compare the "REF" and the "DNI" of both tables and see who has the greater date ("LAST_DATE"); for example:**
FROM TABLE_1

```
       +--------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
       |ID      | NAME    | LASTNAME     |REF       |DNI          | COUNTRY   | MONTH  | LAST_DATE   | 
       +--------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
       |  1     |Juan     |Valverde      |23054     |6124123      | EEUU      |  APRIL |  2021-03-03 |
```

AND FROM TABLE_2:

```
       +--------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
       |ID      | NAME    | LASTNAME     |REF       |DNI          | COUNTRY   | MONTH  | LAST_DATE   | 
       +--------+---------+--------------+----------+-------------+-----------+--------+-------------+
       |  1     |Juan     |Valverde      |23054     |6124123      | EEUU      |  APRIL |  2019-09-03 | 
       |  2     |Juan     |Valverde      |23054     |6124123      | PANAMA    |  JAN   |  2021-01-10 |
```

I have two rows with the same references and dni but different dates and I want to keep the most current date

```
 |  2     |Juan     |Valverde      |23054     |6124123      | PANAMA    |  JAN   |  2021-01-10 |
```

then compare with the "REF" and "DNI" of TABLE_1, if the date of TABLE_1 is greater than TABLE_2 I will keep that line of records in TABLE_1, otherwise I will discard it.
And so with the rest. Any solution?

I hope I have been understood. Best regards. Thank you

Comment: You could use MAX(LAST_DATE) to determine the most recent date.

Comment: Can you give me an example???